# NASM - When to use capitalized letters

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am trying to learn NASM, and I have checked a few tutorials. But some tutorials said that you should write 'mov' while some others said 'MOV' and so on ('int' and 'INT'. Is there a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NASM is not case-sensitive (except for labels and variables) and will gladly accept `mov`, `MOV` or `Mov` as the same opcode.

Comment: Does that apply to hex numbers aswell?

Comment: Yes, you can use 8ah, 8Ah, 8aH or 8AH (or 0x8a, 0h8a etc.)

Comment: I would rather say that NASM is case sensitive, except for opcodes and numbers.

Comment: And register names and directives and keywords

Comment: Can anyone point to the specific place where this is documented ?  Can it be turned on/off as a single blanket behavior ?

Comment: Apart from a small note in [its manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/nasm.1.html), it doesn't seem to be documented, and except for macros, which can be defined as case-sensitive or case-insensitive, is not possible to be changed.

Comment: Watch out for the "known" section names - `.text`, `.data`, `.bss`, etc. These ARE case sensitive and `section .TEXT` will not do what you want!